# React : protect page on react with local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have an application in react and I want to protect all pages with a password
i have header navbar and footer
and when I do this with protected route class if the mail and password are good it redirect me to the component without NavBar and header, only component
how can I protect display all page

```
<ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={analyticsDashboard} />
```

with

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { is } from '@babel/types';
import AppRouter from '../Router';

class ProtectedRoute extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const Component = this.props.component;
        const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem('token');
        
        if(isAuthenticated==='0')
        {
            return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/pages/login' }} />
        }
        return <Component/>
      
    }
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

and thanks to tell me which method can I use on production instead of local storage

Answer (score 0):

you can create a HOC as following

first call this function when you want to set the token value to local storage

```
// call this function in the root component when you want to set the token
function setLocalStorage (key, value) {
  const originalSetItem = localStorage.setItem;

  localStorage.setItem = function(key, value) {
    const event = new Event('itemInserted');
    event.value = value;
    event.key = key;
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
    originalSetItem.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}
```

Second, create a hoc

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function(ComposedComponent) {
  class Authentication extends Component {
    state = {
      isAuthenticated: !!localStorage.getItem('token')
    };

    localStorageSetHandler({ key, value }) {
      if (key !== 'token') return;

      this.setState(({
        isAuthenticated: !!value,
      }))
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      document.addEventListener("itemInserted", this.localStorageSetHandler, false);
    }

    render() {
      const { isAuthenticated } = this.state;

      if (!isAuthenticated) {
        return  <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/pages/login' }} />;
      }
      return <ComposedComponent />;
    }
  }
}
```

then use the hoc you've created to create protected routes like so

```
<Route
  path={'/path'}
  component={RequireAuth(lazy(() => import('./component path')))} // or you can use  component={RequireAuth(YourComponent)}
/>
```

Comment: it's not the problem it still return only the route component

Comment: I need to return the hole page ( protect all application)

Comment: then you have to create a layout and move the logic above into it and wrap each route with the layout. for example 
<ProtectedLayout>route component</ProtectedLayout>